# Android Attach database onupgrade locks database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

On upgrade method i'm renaming my database and copying new database from assets folder.

But on Attach statements it throws an exception on "database locked (code) 5"

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if(oldVersion<newVersion){
     db.close();
        /**
         *  Renaming Database from Databse path
         * 
         */

        new File(Constants.DATABASE_PATH+Constants.DATABSE_NAME).renameTo(new File(Constants.DATABASE_PATH+Constants.DATABASE_NAME_RENAME));


        boolean mm = checkDataBase(Constants.DATABSE_NAME);


        boolean up = checkDataBase(Constants.DATABASE_NAME_RENAME);

        try {
        copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        boolean dbmm = checkDataBase(Constants.DATABSE_NAME);
        boolean dbup = checkDataBase(Constants.DATABASE_NAME_RENAME);
        try{
            String path = Constants.DATABASE_PATH+Constants.DATABSE_NAME;
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);



             File dbFile=myContext.getDatabasePath(Constants.DATABSE_NAME);
```

At the line below it throws database lock (code 5) expection.

```
            db.execSQL(String.format("ATTACH DATABASE '%s' AS BACKUP;",
                    dbFile,null));




          db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+Constants.COMPANY_TABLE_NAME+" SELECT * FROM BACKUP."+Constants.COMPANY_TABLE_NAME);
          db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+Constants.PAGE_TABLE_NAME+" SELECT * FROM BACKUP."+Constants.PAGE_TABLE_NAME);
          db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+Constants.BOOKMARK_TABLE_NAME+" SELECT * FROM BACKUP."+Constants.BOOKMARK_TABLE_NAME);
          db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+Constants.CATALOG_TABLE_NAME+" SELECT * FROM BACKUP."+Constants.CATALOG_TABLE_NAME);
          db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+Constants.Order_Items_TABLE_NAME+" SELECT * FROM BACKUP."+Constants.Order_Items_TABLE_NAME);
          db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+Constants.Order_TABLE_NAME+" SELECT * FROM BACKUP."+Constants.Order_TABLE_NAME);

db.execSQL(String.format("DETACH DATABASE '%s' ;",
    "BACKUP",null));
db.close();       

        }catch(Exception e){




            Log.e("Db", e+"");
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: Please reconsider your approach - this is broken in so many ways. For "database from assets" problem, consider sqlite-asset-helper.

Comment: I guess it´s like on every system....you can´t rename a file while it´s opened...

Comment: but you see i'm closing db connection then renaming

Answer (score 0):

`onUpgrade()` (and `onCreate()`) are run inside a transaction; these methods must not do anything besides executing SQL statements inside that database.

If you are not interested in the contents of the old database, don't bother updating it. Just use a different file name for the new database, and delete the old file whenever you want.

If you *are* interested in the old data, you can attach and copy it after copying the new file.

(And consider using [SQLiteAssetHelper](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-sqlite-asset-helper/).)

Comment: Actually I need to save all the data when database is updated.

Comment: Then trying to copy the new DB from assets does not make sense.

Comment: first i'm renaming my old database as BACKUP
then copying new schema from assets folder and trying to attach backup database with new one so i can copy data into new database and delete backup

Answer (score 0):

db.close();
doesn't need to close db manually.